# How do you debug Maven plugin tests executed with the maven-invoker-plugin?

Tags: maven

I would like to attach to some tests for a Maven plugin being executed with the `maven-invoker-plugin`. How does one do this? I can't seem to find any resources and it doesn't seem to be by simply doing:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9001" mvn clean install
```

I mean -- I can connect this way, but when the `maven-invoker-plugin` starts, it just sits there. Forever...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must be aware that maven-invoker-plugin invokes a separate instance of Maven for running integration tests like a manual call of **mvn** with the appropriate configuration options. That's the reason why maven sticks...

You can put the appropriate options into *[invoker.mavenOpts](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#mavenOpts)* or into a **invoker.properties** file.
An other option would be to change the *[mavenExecuteable](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#mavenExecutable)* and use mvnDebug instead of mvn.

Comment: +1: I agree. I was, however, thinking the forked Maven was invoked in the same JVM and that it was just invoked as a regular class. Apparently, this is really forking a separate process.

Comment: It's not a separate class nor anything else it's really like calling mvn manualy on command line (see the [maven invoker share component](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/usage.html) which handles the sub call.

Comment: Thanks, `invoker.mavenOpts` did the trick but `invoker.mavenExecuteable` had absolutely no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, (after further inspectiong of the `build.log`) with the above mentioned way, it freezes simply because Maven is waiting for you to connect with a remote debugger a second time -- this time for the forked process.